Upgrade from Spring 4 to 5, and entityManagerFactory bean no longer creates(xml config)
I have an application that was using Spring 4.3 with XML configuration and it was working correctly but when upgrading to Spring 5 and trying to re-deploy in WebLogic I get:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available:org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="${database.type}" />
            <property name="showSql" value="${database.showSql}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="melpu"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager">
        <bean class="a18k.core.util.AdvancedPersistenceUnitManager">
            <!-- <property name="sEnv" value="${app.env}" /> -->
            <!-- <property name="ssoEntityId" value="${sso.entityid}" /> -->
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <array>
                    <value>a18k.core.model.security</value>
                    <value>a18k.core.model.alert</value>
                    <value>gov.va.nca.mel.model</value>
                    <value>gov.va.nca.mel.model.metrics</value>
                </array>
            </property>
            <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="melpu"/>
            <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>
    </property>


    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="${database.showSql}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="${database.showSql}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="${database.showSql}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4" />
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
            <entry key="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="gov.va.nca.mel.persistence.MELEntityInterceptor" />
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix" value="_HIST" />
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name" value="VER" />
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name"
                value="REV_TYPE" />
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change"
                value="true" />
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field"
                value="false" />
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete" value="true" />
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.default_schema" value="MEL" />
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.use_revision_entity_with_native_id"
                value="false" />
<!--                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> -->

        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

class referencing emf:
@Component("hibernateUtils")
public class HibernateUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateUtils.class);

    @Resource(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManagerFactory  entityManagerFactory;

    public void logStatistics() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("", getStatistics());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Statistics getStatistics() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = ((EntityManagerFactoryInfo) entityManagerFactory).getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
        return ((SessionFactory) emf).getStatistics();
    }
}

Did something change with how these have to be configured? I haven't found any documentation saying how beans are instantiated in XML has changed.
